# Limit on concurrent connections: Determined by webserver or database?

Tags: web-server, database, concurrency

Does the webserver or is it the database that limits the number of concurrent connections?

Comment: Not forgetting the underlying operating system may impose a limit too.

Answer (score 1):

"All of the above."

Without more information about your configuration it's very hard to answer.  Typically. both webservers and databases have configuration options that either explicitly or implicitly limit the number of concurrent connections.  And as @Ben points out, it's possible to do this at the operating system level, too.

If this is more than an academic question (that is, if you're running into a specific problem to  which you're looking for a solution), give us more information and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Actually, this is just an academic question. I've read a lot about concurrency on various blogs and a few research papers, but they mainly talk about high-end stuff which I have trouble to understand. That's why I need to understand some basics first and hence, the question above.

Comment: Some specific examples: For Apache, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients.  For MySQL, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections.